# Z-index hover jquery issue

Tags: jquery, hover, z-index, slideshow

I have a transparent png over a slideshow box, settings use z-index. I need to be able to hover over the top/transparent image and have the underlying slideshow start and stop on hover-off. The script I'm using works well for the slideshow but I need the top transparent div to be the 'trigger'. How do I add this div to this script? Let's give the transparent image the ID of "trans_image." Also, if you can link to a good tutorial on this I would appreciate it!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade', 
    speed: 1,
     delay:  1, 
        speed:  1
  }).cycle("pause").hover(function() {
        $(this).cycle('resume');
  },function(){
        $(this).cycle('pause');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your HTML layout, but have you tried this?

```
$('#trans_image').hover(function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle('resume');
    },
    function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle('pause');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you dgvid- I was making it a lot harder than necessary- this works! AND I understand why.